# WannaCry Source Code

Tags: virus, ransomware, source-code, wannacry, worm

Maybe this is a stupid question: Is the WannaCry source code public?

https ://github.com/svenvdz/wannacry

https: //github.com/Hackstar7/WanaCry

https: //github.com/fadyosman/WannaCrySample

I didn't really find anything on github or google. Is the `svenvdz` repo the source? Everything else wannacry related on github is definitely not it. I thought it would've been made public by now.

Comment: Who would release it? Afaik, the source for the eternal blue exploits are released (from the NSA-leak) that are used by wannacry but the source itself isn't open source.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the WannaCry source code public?

No. It is not.

That is why malware researchers have been laboring to reverse engineer the ransomware functionality using tools such as debuggers and disassemblers. For some malware, source code may eventually leak out, and it makes life easier for a malware researcher, but in general all we have is a binary or a DLL.

> I thought it would've been made public by now.

That depends on the original authors of the ransomware and whether they consciously or accidentally leak the source code, or if they have a security breach and the code is stolen from them. They did not consciously or accidentally leak it yet or have it stolen as far as I know.

Comment: Then what's https://github.com/svenvdz/wannacry/blob/master/worm.c ? It even has the domain name that stops the attack listed.

Comment: That is not an actual source code leak. That code is generated by retdec.com, a decompiler.

Comment: And it's barely readable.